# Calling API with Javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, corda

What is the correct way to call this API? The api url is: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd

I tried with this code

```
<p id="demo">
 </p>
 <script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.bitcoin;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd" + new Date().getTime(), true);
    xmlhttp.send();
 </script>
```

however the value I get is [object Object]. I want to get the value in "usd".

Where am I wrong? Thx

Replaces myObj with myObj.usd but returns null value

Comment: have you tried console logging the `myObj`?  does it have a `bitcoin` attribute?

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.bitcoin.usd;`

Answer (score 1):

The API returns in the form of `{"bitcoin":{"usd": -insert value here-}}`, so you have to use `myObj.bitcoin.usd`

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `usd` part of the object when you set the innerHTML as @SuspenseFallback mentioned.

You also need to remove the `+ new Date().getTime()` part from your URL string. I don't see a date part in the [API docs](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) for the `price` endpoint.

Comment: Your tip worked with the friend above! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you should use the fetch method. the better and the modern way of calling API using native javascript.

There is no problem with the way you did it but there are a few things that you can do with fetch and not with XHR.

you can read more about fetch by this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

there is an example of using fetch:

```
fetch(
  "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd"
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

or you can use async-await to achieve the same result :

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd"
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
})();
```

> note: I have used Javascript Self Invoking Functions which is a
> function that calls itself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm going to study about it, I'm still pretty noob. already opened my mind

Answer (score 0):

The answers quickly resolve the issue, however I ran into another problem where there are hyphenated words.

Sample API:
https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin-cash&vs_currencies=usd